# How is swap on mid-2013 MacBook Air w/ PCIe SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd, memory, performance

There appears to be confusing and incomplete information about the PCIe SSDs in mid-2013 MacBook Air 11" and 13" (especially the 128GB models), where a different **queue depth** may result in different speed test results. http://www.anandtech.com/show/7085/the-2013-macbook-air-review-13inch/8

In simple terms, **how how much slower is swap on the 128GB PCIe SSD compared to the main memory on the 4GB LDDR3 in the mid-2013 MacBook Air 11" and 13"?**  **What about 256GB?**

I cannot really find any comprehensive comparison on the topic specific to the proprietary SSDs used by Apple in mid-2013 MacBook Air, especially [comparison between 128GB and 256GB models](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129167/how-fast-is-256gb-to-128gb-on-mid-2013-macbook-air).  A good answer would include methodology through which it's derived.

Comment: what is the purpose of your question other then wanting to know?

Comment: @Buscar웃, to make a decision whether 8GB of LPDDR3 is worth it, or if 4GB would suffice; to see if upgrading to 256GB drive would make sense instead etc.

Comment: Going from the 256 and 8 is the best, now it is a question of budget. The only measurable difference (to us humans) is when the SWAP has to be used. The size does matter! so a larger SSD is better if you have a lots of stuff. (but that is purely personal decision). Your first bottleneck is your RAM.